# Dynamic number of input fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working in a installment payment Component, and I need a dynamic list of **Form Inputs**, according the number of installment payments the User selects (from 1 to 12).

I don't know how I could get the values of the future **Form Inputs**.

When I have just one Form Input, I use **'v-model'** to capture the value of the input field that already exists.

But with multiple instances of a component inside a loop, I can't figure it out.

```
// The User choose 6
// The value 6 (Number) goes to a property inside data() with v-model

    data () {
      return {
       numberOfFields: 6 
      }
    }
```

Then to a v-for

```
<template v-for="n in numberOfFields">
  <input type="text" v-model="????">
</template>
```

I don't want to create every possibility like:

```
data(){
  return {
    inputField1: '',
    inputField2: '',
    inputField3: '',
    //  up to inputField12
  }
}
```

I want to capture the value of the input field **only** if the input exists, but without creating every possible option beforehand.

Comment: Try `v-model="data[n]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<template v-for="n in numberOfFields">
  <input type="text" v-model="$data['inputField' + n]">
</template>
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      numberOfFields: 6,
      inputField1: '11',
      inputField2: '22',
      inputField3: '33',
      inputField4: '44',
      inputField5: '55',
      inputField6: '66',
      //  up to inputField12
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="n in numberOfFields">
    <input type="text" v-model="$data['inputField' + n]"> {{ $data['inputField' + n] }}<br>
  </template>
</div>
```

But this is unusual. Generally, we create another object and use it (instead of the `data` root).

Example using another object, called `fields`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      numberOfFields: 6,
      fields: {
        inputField1: '11',
        inputField2: '22',
        inputField3: '33',
        inputField4: '44',
        inputField5: '55',
        inputField6: '66',
        //  up to inputField12
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b>Using numberOfFields:</b><br>
  <template v-for="n in numberOfFields">
    <input type="text" v-model="fields['inputField' + n]"> {{ fields['inputField' + n] }}
  </template>
  <br><hr><br>
  <b>Using (val, key):</b><br>
  <template v-for="(val, key) in fields">
    <input type="text" v-model="fields[key]"> {{ fields[key] }}
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, it's not that much of a difference, though. I will update the answer in a minute.

Comment: There you go, check it out.